# How to override deprecated warning in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings

Is there a `#pragma` to override a compile time warning, e.g.:

```
warning: 'ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/Headers/ADBannerView.h:111)
```

I have to keep compatibility for pre-4.2 iOS devices by:

```
NSString *iAdSize = (osVersion >= 4.2) ? ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Yes there is

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wno-deprecated-declarations"
//deprecated function
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

If you ever wonder what the proper syntax is for a certain error just find it in Xcode then look at the quick help

[image]

Comment: I had to use #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations" for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

There's a build setting to toggle warning for deprecated functions.

Though the right way to do this would be check for OS version at runtime, and execute the deprecated method if necessary, or the new one otherwise.

Comment: I am looking for a switch to turn off one specific deprecated warning which I know what I am doing, but not turning off all. Thx.

Comment: In that case, check out my other answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress a specific deprecated warning by creating a 'Deprecated.h' file, in which you declare the deprecated methods as good in a category.

Comment: this is a bad idea, you should instead just suppress the specific warning using the pragma syntax